# Debug Run In Android Studio Fails With: Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed

Tags: android, android-library

All right, I have scoured the internet and I'm still struggling with this stuff. I have an android library (the full code can be found [here](https://github.com/CleverChuk/mips-simulator/tree/fpu)) that I'm working on. So gist is, after upgrading to Android studio Flamingo and the other lots to the latest version, the debug run from the UI essentially stopped connecting to either an emulator or a real device. I have no clue why. Below is the build log, but hey you can clone the project and try it yourself.

```
05/31 21:02:51: Launching 'testldc1()' on Pixel 4 API 30.
Running tests

Open logcat panel for emulator Pixel 4 API 30
Executing tasks: [:mips:connectedDebugAndroidTest] in project /Users/yuck/dev/repos/mips-simulator


> Configure project :mips
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The option setting 'android.experimental.testOptions.emulatorSnapshots.maxSnapshotsForTestFailures=0' is experimental.","sources":[{}]}

> Task :mips:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mips:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mips:generateDebugResValues
> Task :mips:generateDebugResources
> Task :mips:packageDebugResources
> Task :mips:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mips:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :mips:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :mips:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :mips:processDebugManifest
> Task :mips:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :mips:generateDebugRFile
> Task :mips:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata
> Task :mips:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :mips:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
> Task :mips:mapDebugAndroidTestSourceSetPaths
> Task :mips:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :mips:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :mips:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :mips:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
> Task :mips:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mips:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :mips:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mips:packageDebugAssets
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
> Task :mips:compressDebugAndroidTestAssets
> Task :mips:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :mips:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :mips:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :mips:desugarDebugAndroidTestFileDependencies
> Task :mips:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses
> Task :mips:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug
> Task :mips:writeDebugAndroidTestSigningConfigVersions
> Task :mips:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :mips:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource
> Task :mips:processDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :mips:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
> Task :mips:dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:mergeLibDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:mergeProjectDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:packageDebugAndroidTest
> Task :mips:createDebugAndroidTestApkListingFileRedirect

> Task :mips:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 0 tests on Pixel_4_API_30(AVD) - 11


> Task :mips:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
41 actionable tasks: 41 executed
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mips:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/yuck/dev/repos/mips-simulator/mips/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
```

It does say that test failed which is indeed true, however, the debugger never attached and my break points were pointless. This makes it extremely hard for me figured why it's failing and my tool is failing at this point.

I've used the solutions that suggested using `androidx` runner and even followed the instruction [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup) to setup my tests dependencies from scratch. Tried excluding `junit` dependency and only have the one from `andriodx` but still no go. And cleared cache and invalidate and the other obvious things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Edit Configurations -> Debugger-> Set debug type to Java Only[image: Screen shot]

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is a non-starter for me since I need to debug native code.

Add the simplest of app projects (say, `mipsTest`) alongside your library project, resulting in a "multi-module project". You can leave the app bare but ensure it contains your `MipsSimulatorTest.java` file (or whatever test files you choose in `androidTest`). Then run/debug your library tests and it will work because it's associated with an app.

[image: mult-module project example][1]

This is a bummer of a workaround. I would expect testing a library on device to work because `AndroidJUnitRunner` is the hosting process regardless of lib or app.